# install laravel on appserv without using php artisan serv

Tags: laravel

I have installed laravel project via composer in

```
c:/projectname
```

When I want to work on the project I open msdos and write PHP artisan serv. Also, I have already appserv server on the computer.
How can I install laravel project on appserv and work with it on appserv?
How can I install the project on appserv  and access it without writing PHP artisan serv?
How can in export it to cpanel?
my appserv version is AppServ 8.6.0, my laravel version is 5.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the laravel But can't access the main page?If so,you can access localhost/your-laravel-folder/public to see the main page.

Comment: i can access laravel but i have to run msdos and run this command php artisan serv i mean how can i access laravel via appserv without using msdos

Comment: @AwarPulldozer Your appserv root folder has a 'www' folder you need put your laravel folder in the www folder.insure your appserv's apache is online.Then you access  localhost/your-laravel-folder/public you can see the web has run .

Comment: If you php artisan serv ,infact it run a php http server not apache.